# JQuery Panel - Left Menu Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a left menu made of jQuery panel.
Its height is full screen. How can I shorten it to a size as high as its content (ul attribute in this scenario). I cannot even manually edit its height from div style **(width:100px;height:10px did not work.)** . Any specific reason for jQuery panel ?

Any idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!--LEFT TOP MENU PANEL-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="leftMenu" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a" style="width:170px;">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="false"><a id="a" href="#">Show A Items</a>
            </li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a id="b" href="#">Show B Items</a>
            </li>
            <li style="display:none" data-icon="false"><a>Show C Items</a>
            </li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a id="c" data-transition="none" href="#show_pollen">Show D Items</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: you wanna to  fix the height of the sidebar  as of the content has means (width:100px;height:auto;) this work ....if u have three data height will be re-sized according to this...

Comment: Vinoth, this is still not working. 
style="width:170px; height:auto

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just ended up editing jquery.mobile.css.
Found .ui-panel 's min-height attribute, and set it to 0%, 
also might be important to state that max-height is set to 20%.

```
.ui-panel{width:17em;min-height: 0%;max-height: 20%;border-width:0;position:absolute;top: 160px;display:block;}
```